# Определение простых замкнутые цепочек в графе

Tags: алгоритм, графы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет, есть такая цепочка из балок связанных между собой (дана та, что слева). Как найти замкнутые цепочки, которые не содержат вложенных? В данном случае их будет три: 1-2-3-5, 1-5-3-4. Знаю как это можно как-то помощью графа, но не пойму как на основании еджей сделать граф, так как балка 1 и 3 цельны, но к ним примыкает посередине другая балка и для графа они же же должны делиться на два отдельных эджа.
Два вопроса:

1. Какой есть алгоритм, чтоб найти простые замкнутые цепочки
2. Как правильно делить балки, чтоб получить два отдельных эджа

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть иначе - балка это Вершина (node), а стык - это Ребро (edge).

Comment: @Kromster А что насчет поиска всех циклов?

Comment: Это вторая половина вашего решения. Можете поискать по ней информацию отдельно (например, в похожих вопросах справа)